# Background processes running while idle using lots of CPU

Tags: windows-10, vmware, process-explorer

I downloaded Windows 10 to my VMware machine and it works great but I've noticing slowdown on my real computer when I leave my virtual machine idle. I have Process Explorer open and when I have it run idle, a bunch of processes run in the background.

[image]

Seems like it's trying to scan for viruses or cleaning junk off my hard drive. Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the scheduled idle maintenance task which runs when the PC is idle. Run task scheduler and disalbe the automatic and idle maintenance under `Task Scheduler -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Task Scheduler`

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't see it inside the task scheduler.

Comment: I don't have Win10 running, so I assumed it was the same like in 8.1.